# Resources in Winforms Application using CodeDOM

Tags: c#, winforms, codedom

I have an application that deploys smaller applications.
Those smaller ones basically consist of an icon (not a form icon) and a notifyicon control that needs an icon as well.

My question is: How to embed resources in the small application and compile it using CodeDOM?
I need the icon from the "bigger" application (the one that compiles) as they would have the same icons.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.embeddedresources.aspx

Comment: Well, thank you for your concern, but this is not what I need.
I need to know how to ember files like *.ico not a *.resources file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking is how to embed resources in an assembly built with CodeDOM (which is the only thing it will do, w.r.t. resources) then see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.embeddedresources.aspx.

If what you are asking is how to create .resource files programmattically, **this has nothing to do with CodeDOM**  (i.e. it's not code and not an executable).  But, possibly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx will point you in the right direction/